# Audio/Video editor for macOS

Tags: audio, video-editing

I have a short MP4 video (with sound), and a separate short MP3 file. I am looking for a way to replace the audio of the first file with the audio of the second one.

Is there a lightweight app solution for doing it on a Mac?

Comment: Please see http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation for advice on 'software recommendation' questions.

Comment: Thanks. Please let me know if there is anything in the recommendations of that link that is not being applied here.

Comment: Apple's iMovie fits the bill. Try that and post if you discarded the obvious choice for whatever reasons you find. Speaking about what "lightweight" means might make this more objectively answerable.ive edited out online since that doesn't fit here as well as web apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If lightweight means command line, then get `ffmpeg`

1. https://brew.sh - install homebrew package manager
2. `brew install ffmpeg`
3. profit

See any of the plethora of tutorials online or questions on the network :

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446578/how-to-replace-audio-track-in-mkv-file-on-ubuntu-11-10
- https://superuser.com/questions/800234/how-to-replace-an-audio-stream-in-a-video-file-with-multiple-audio-streams
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/how-to-add-a-new-audio-not-mixing-into-a-video-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Perfect – excellent command-line solution, and I found all the help I needed in [your third link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11783474/635806). Cheers!